# How do I push a string into IO input being called from another function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a function, that woks similar to (or), that takes in a Bool and returns True if the user input is true or the Bool is True.

**I can not change anything about orFunc. It must stay the way it is**

```
orFunc :: Bool -> IO Bool
orFunc xs = do ys <- getLine
               let rev1 = xs || (read ys::Bool)
               return rev1
```

so.. (orFunc False) with a user input of True would return True.

Now let's say, I want to test this function, with a series of automated inputs.

The function tester, calls our orFunc, and wants to push the word "False", conveniently located in our false.txt file, into orFunc. This way, I don't need to type the word "False" into the function every single time. It will automatically grab it from the false.txt. How do I go about doing this when orFunc doesn't take input as a parameter?

Here an example of what it should look like. This doesn't work but it's something I tried.

```
tester :: IO Bool -> IO Bool
tester xs = do ys <- readFile "false.txt"
               xs <- ys
               return xs
```

Here's how I would run some test's on it.

```
{--This will return True because True || False = True --}
tester (orFunc True)

{--This will return False because False || False = False --}
tester (orFunc False)
```

Comment: Well, this is just silly. If you want `orFunc` to be testable with automatic input, then it should _not_ include `getLine` and probably no `IO` at all, but instead just take that input as an _argument_ and obtain the input elsewhere that doesn't need any interesting testing. Those parts that really do need `IO` should be reduced to a minumum that doesn't need to be tested, or else tested with proper `IO` as well, i.e. with a seperate program that pipes data to your executable.

Comment: I challenge the claim that you can not change anything about `orFunc`. This is not a realistic description of any system I have worked with in my career.

Comment: why can't you change orFunc?

Comment: @user253751 I added that restriction because I am primarily focused on unit testing. orFunc works, but I need to ensure each input produces it's expected output. Testing the IO input is crucial for what i'm doing. Daniel made a great point by saying I could duplicate file descriptors into stdIn, so i am currently working on implementing that.

Comment: @18dwhyte if your input comes from a file instead of from the user, you're not really testing the IO input, are you? You're testing your own *pretend* IO input.

Comment: @user253751 You are correct. The point of the text file is to simulate user input so I can ensure that their inputs give out the correct output.

Comment: @18dwhyte you can also do that by modifying `orFunc` so that it has a `String` input instead of using `IO`. Which is easier.

Comment: On top of what's been already said, I would consider using external tools to supply the text, rather than faking user input within the same executable. For example, this bash script: `myTests < testInput.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice is Don't. Instead, abstract `orFunc` into a part that does `IO` and a part that does your business logic, and test the business logic independently of the `IO`.

But if you are absolutely set, one way to do this would be to open your file and duplicate its file descriptor to stdin's. Like this:

```
import System.IO
import System.Posix.IO

main = do
    fd <- openFile "false.txt" ReadMode >>= handleToFd
    dupTo fd stdInput
    orFunc False
```

This only works on Linux-alikes. It's possible Windows has a similar API somewhere, but I'm not familiar enough with it to give good pointers about where.